# Apache 2.4 failing to load mod_wsgi.so on Yosemite

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

## Problem

Using OS X Yosemite and Python 2.7, I am trying to follow a simple [hello world in Flask with Apache WSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084791/flask-hello-world-using-apache-and-mod-wsgi-shows-files-in-webroot-only) but am receiving this error when executing `apachectl -S`:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 171 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/mod_wsgi.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/mod_wsgi.so, 10): image not found
```

## What I've tried

First, I placed the file in `/usr/libexec/apache2/` with the other `mod_*` files. Second, I tried to follow [Graham Dumpleton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10447806/1830334) and verify the following steps:

**1. That you don't have extensions hidden and have added the extension twice.**

```
gwg$ file /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

**2. That the mod_wsgi.so file is readable to whatever Apache service user is.**

I'm not sure exactly how to do this, but I just checked the file's permissions against other `.so` files. For example:

```
gwg$ ls -l mod_vhost_alias.so 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  19472 Sep  9 18:11 mod_vhost_alias.so
```

and

```
gwg$ ls -l mod_wsgi.so 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  209564 Dec  4 17:05 mod_wsgi.so
```

**3. That your Apache is 32 [64] bit.**

```
I'm not sure how to do this.
```

**4. That your Python is 32 [64] bit.**

Per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406849/1830334):

```
>>> import struct
>>> print struct.calcsize("P") * 8
64
```

**5. That your Python is installed for all users and not just user you installed it as.**

```
gwg$ sudo su -
root# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

## Question

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using `brew` was the easiest for me to run `wsgi` on Mac OS X. 
This is the sequence.

1. `brew tap homebrew/apache`
2. `brew install mod_wsgi`
3. If necessary `xcode-select --install`
4. You must manually edit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to include `LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/local/Cellar/mod_wsgi/3.X/libexec/mod_wsgi.so`

   - X is 5 as of Dec, 2014, but just follow the instruction what is shown on the screen
5. Check if everything's OK

   - `httpd -t` => Syntax OK